# using """ string does Not as what I expected

Tags: python

```
elif Antwort == "yes":
    print("""Es ist schade, dass es Dir so geht wie mir.
    Willst Du also auswandern?""")

Es ist schade, dass es Dir so geht wie mir.
    Willst Du also auswandern?
```

I use the `"""` to be able to split the string over two lines but the code displayed does not start from the same starting point.

Maybe I need to use "\n" and string summing (advice from my friend)?
But I really don't know how to write the next code...

Comment: It's really not clear what you expect. I believe `print` in this situation will in fact print *exactly* the string you gave it, so it's not correct to say it's not preserving the original format.

Comment: If the duplicate is not the answer to what you _tried_ to ask, please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the string includes literally everything you type, including the leading spaces.  You have a couple of choices.  You can shift the text to the left margin:

```
elif Antwort == "yes":
    print("""Es ist schade, dass es Dir so geht wie mir.
Willst Du also auswandern?""")
```

or you can use regular strings, concatenated:

```
elif Antwort == "yes":
    print("Es ist schade, dass es Dir so geht wie mir.\n"
    "Willst Du also auswandern?")
```